# If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x},\ \text{x rational}$, does $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist? Does $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ exist for any $a$?

Tags: calculus, limits

The definition of a limit at a point $a$ is that

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x, |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

After the $\forall x$ in $(1)$ is there an implicit statement $x \in \mathbb{R}$? That is, is the definition of limit actually

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x, (x \in \mathbb{R} \land |x-a|<\delta) \implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

Consider

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x},\ \text{x rational}$$

That is, $f$ is not defined at irrational $x$.

Does $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist?

Does $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ exist for any $a$?

Comment: The definition is $\forall x\in D(f)$ where $D(f)$ is the domain of $f$. This is usually taken to be $\mathbb{R}$ although in your case it is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The only value of $a$ for which the limit will not exist is $a=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you consider the domain of the function. The question suggests that it is just the rational numbers. That set is a perfectly respectable domain to ask about limits of functions on. The definition of "limit" will require $|f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ *for all* $x$ *in the domain of* $f$.

The limit at $\infty$ of your function will be $0$.